# UITableView push UIView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, segue

I have a UITableView which is populate with CoreData, when I click on a cell it goes on a UIView for details, so I have a push segue between the views, but when I test it, it goes wrong, because when I go on the UITableView trough the mainView or trough my menu, it looks like that it goes on the UITableView but with the menu of de detail view, or it directly show fully the detail view:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXN9U.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9878.png)

But I want this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muZlw.png)

The code used :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let secondViewController = segue.destination as! ActualitesDetailsViewController

    secondViewController.receivedData = "hello"
}
```

Any solutions? I'm just trying to open a uiview when your clicking on a uitableviewcell which send some data to the view.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEIuX.png)

To access on tableview trough the main view:

```
class func actualitesViewController() -> ActualitesViewController? {
    return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ActualitesViewController") as? ActualitesViewController
}
```

It was because of in viewdidload:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
```

Now I want to change the color of the header of the segue "> ACTUALITES" how to do ?

Comment: It's not fully clear what do you want to do. Correct me if I'm wrong: you have 2 viewControllers (use this name instead of "view" next time), which are connected with menu. One viewController has UITableView and second viewController - detailViewController.
If you want to share some data between controllers you are going in right way.
Can you give more details?

Comment: @RomanHouse Yes the goal is to open a view on tableviewcell click and show details of this one, but I don't know how to do and when I go at the tableview through the menu or the main view I have a bad render, I get the 2 first images, but I want to get the third, the tableview.

Comment: Seems you have bad setup of navigation in your storyboard. Check a class of controller from which you have arrow with "segue" identifier. It should be same as UITableView's controller class.

Comment: @RomanHouse look my edit the picture of my segue

Comment: can you add code of your action of menu button which provides you on the screen with table view?

Comment: @RomanHouse look my edit please

Comment: When I'm deleting the segue, the uitableview is loaded successfully